# How to make woocommerce add cart function works for not logged in users?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
WC()->cart->add_to_cart(8, 1);
```

I am using the above code to add dynamic products in the cart. It's working fine when I am logged in but it fails to add products while I am not logged in. How to fix this?

Comment: What other code are you using? The above code should work fine.

Comment: Navigate to WooCommerce -> Settings -> Checkout tab, ensure "Enable guest checkout" is ticked.

Comment: @rnevius No other code

Comment: @AnandShah It's already enabled :(

Comment: As @rnevius suggested, provide the complete code you are using. Also try switching to another theme and see if the issue resolves then.

Comment: Okay.. I ill try. I don't use any other code. Just using this only. Passing values using variables instead of the current value  WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product, $qty);  it's working fine when I am logged in

Answer (score 2):

Answering 2 years later in case anyone has a similar problem.
I solved this by adding first adding the item to the cart, and then setting the woocommerce session cookie:

```
wc()->cart->add_to_cart($id);
wc()->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);
```